# React-Redux Slider undefined value when passing onwards the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

This is my first post so I'm sorry if I'm doing it wrong. So, I've started creating a webpage for my portfolio with React and Redux but I hit a point where I can't find the solution or the flaw in my logic. The page is that the user can select a skill and then the pointer to the value he knows. I can save the skills to localStorage but I can't manage to pass the skill value from the slider to save it. If anyone can help with any tip or info of where I m doing wrong please help.

This are some of the components:

1. [slider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHesM.png)
2. [skillsComp whee the slider is passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZccH.png)
3. [listSkills Comp where skillsComp and Slider is passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCt1W.png)
4. [redux actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5QwI.png)
5. [redux reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6eQk.png)
6. and this is the console output: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wor0.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem: Not Dispatching Action

The problems that I'm seeing are in image #1 of the `SkillSliderBar` component.  There might be other issue too, I haven't looked further then this.

First of all, your destructured props are missing the `addSkillValue` function from `mapDispatchToProps`.

You defined a function `handleChange` to call the `addSkillValue` function, **but you never call handleChange**.  Instead you are calling `changeValue` which updates the local component state.

You probably don't need a local state at all.  You can use the `skillValue` from `mapStateToProps` as the `value` for your inputs.  To set the value, call `addSkillValue` from `mapDispatchToProps`.

Make sure that the `onChange` function for your inputs is being called with the *value* first and not the *event*.  If it is being called with the event then your `handleChange` would look like:

```
const handleChange = e => {
  addSkillValue(e.target.value);
}
```

#### Suggestions: State Shape

It looks like you only have a skill value in your state for the current skill.  Probably what you want is to store an array of skill objects with properties `name` and `value`.  Or possibly a key-value object where the keys are the skill names and the values are the skill values.  I'm not sure if you *need* the `currentSkillName`.  You can update the value for any skill by dispatching an action that contains both the new value and the name of the skill that you are updating.